# “to check IN on someone” OR “to check on someone“?

Tags: meaning, usage

If I mean : “to make sure someone is doing okay, be it in their work, health, or otherwise”,

*Have “to check IN on someone” AND “to check on someone“ the same meaning ?*

Also, recently, someone wrote me : “Thank you for checking up on me”,

*Is it correct as well ? Different ?*

Answer (score 1):

In the sense you mean in your example

> to make sure someone is doing okay, be it in their work, health, or otherwise

I think *check up on* is the best as this can carry the sense of finding out about their welfare. It can of course also have the sense of monitoring them in a work place or elsewhere as can *check on*. I would not use *check in* but that may be a dialect issue as it may be current in the US dialect(s).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... and further details.
SO ... I could perhaps decide on using mainly:
   1 - to check up on someone,
   2 - to check on someone,
I will leave out “IN” !  
Thanks a lot. It’s a very useful clarification for me,